# Showing loading animation in center of page while making a call to Action method in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery

My application makes several calls to an Action method (ASP .NET MVC) which returns a Json object. When the application is waiting for this method to return its data I want to display a loading animation in the center of the page. How would I accomplish this? I know that I should use JQuery but that's all I know.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I defined two functions in Site.Master:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var spinnerVisible = false;
    function showProgress() {
        if (!spinnerVisible) {
            $("div#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
            spinnerVisible = true;
        }
    };
    function hideProgress() {
        if (spinnerVisible) {
            var spinner = $("div#spinner");
            spinner.stop();
            spinner.fadeOut("fast");
            spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

And special section:

```
    <div id="spinner">
        Loading...
    </div>
```

Visual style is defined in CSS:

```
div#spinner
{
    display: none;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background:url(spinner.gif) no-repeat center #fff;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    font:normal 16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index:2;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain where those javascript functions are being called?

Comment: Those JavaScript functions could be called in Ajax calls. showProgress() could be called when the Ajaxcall is started and hideProgress() could be called in a complete or success/error function of the Ajaxcall.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by displaying a div (if you want to do it in a modal manner you could use [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) - or one of the many other modal dialog plugins out there) prior to the request then just waiting until the call back succeeds as a quick example you can you $.getJSON as follows (you might want to use .ajax if you want to add proper error handling)

```
$("#ajaxLoader").show(); //Or whatever you want to do
$.getJSON("/AJson/Call/ThatTakes/Ages", function(result) {
    //Process your response
    $("#ajaxLoader").hide();
});
```

If you do this several times in your app and want to centralise the behaviour for all ajax calls you can make use of the global AJAX events:-

```
$("#ajaxLoader").ajaxStart(function() { $(this).show(); })
               .ajaxStop(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

---

Using blockUI is similar for example with mark up like:-

```
<a href="/Path/ToYourJson/Action" id="jsonLink">Get JSON</a>
<div id="resultContainer" style="display:none">
And the answer is:-
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>

<div id="ajaxLoader" style="display:none">
    <h2>Please wait</h2>
    <p>I'm getting my AJAX on!</p>
</div>
```

And using jQuery:-

```
$(function() {
    $("#jsonLink").click(function(e) {
        $.post(this.href, function(result) {
            $("#resultContainer").fadeIn();
            $("#result").text(result.Answer);
        }, "json");
        return false;
    });
    $("#ajaxLoader").ajaxStart(function() {
                          $.blockUI({ message: $("#ajaxLoader") });
                     })
                    .ajaxStop(function() { 
                          $.unblockUI();
                     });
});
```

Comment: Voted this one up as it is more thorough and structurally better. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that it is similar to those already exposed here is this one. Just before the closing body tag place this html:

```
<div id="resultLoading" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto;">
    <div style="width: 340px; height: 200px; text-align: center; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto; z-index: 10; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="uil-default-css">
            <img src="/images/loading-animation1.gif" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
        </div>
        <div class="loader-text" style="display: block; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 300;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Finally, replace `.loader-text element's` content on the fly on every navigation event and turn on the `#resultloading` div, note that it is initially hidden.

```
var showLoader = function (text) {
    $('#resultLoading').show();
    $('#resultLoading').find('.loader-text').html(text);
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(window).on("beforeunload ", function () {
        showLoader('Loading, please wait...');
    });
});
```

This can be applied to any html based project with jQuery where you don't know which pages of your administration area will take too long to finish loading.

The gif image is 176x176px but you can use any transparent gif animation, please take into account that the image size is not important as it will be maxed to 150x150px.

Also, the function showLoader can be called on an element's click to perform an action that will further redirect the page, that is why it is provided ad an individual function. i hope this can also help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is how did it works like a charm.

### CSS

```
#loader {
position:fixed;
left:1px;
top:1px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;

background: url('../images/ajax-loader100X100.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

---

in _layout file inside body tag but outside the container div. Every time page loads it shows loading. Once page is loaded JS fadeout(second)

---

```
<div id="loader">
</div>
```

---

JS at the bottom of _layout file

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// With the element initially shown, we can hide it slowly:
 $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
</script>
```