# show() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to display a loading spinner when a user clicks on the submit button.  I tried implementing the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807408/showing-loading-animation-in-center-of-page-while-making-a-call-to-action-method), but it's not working.

I have validated that the function is being called and that the target div is being found by jQuery by tossing in an **alert(spinner.innerHTML)** as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var spinner = $("div#spinner");
    });
    var spinnerVisible = false;
    function showProgress() {
        if (!spinnerVisible) {
            alert(spinner.innerHTML);
            spinner.show();
            spinnerVisible = true;
        }
    };
    function hideProgress() {
        if (spinnerVisible) {
            spinner.hide();
            spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

As expected, when I click on my button, I get an alert window with the text "Loading..." which is the text from my div.  However, if I add a second alert **after** the call to **spinner.show();** it doesn't pop up, which leads me to believe that the call to **spinner.show();** is causing jQuery to fail.

This is my first foray into jQuery, so I'm struggling with how to debug this and find out what is breaking.

Comment: If you're using firefox, open the `error console (CTRL+SHIFT+J)`, do you see any error ?

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` are asynchronous.  If you want something to happen after the element is shown or hidden, you need to include it as part of the method's callback.

Comment: @IswantoSan I am using Chrome.  The only error in the Java Console is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  Could this be the error?  This is after fixing the scope of the spinner.

Comment: @JustinHoldsclaw: Have you include jquery library in your code?

Comment: @IswantoSan: I am using Visual Web Developer 2010, which I understood to include jQuery by default.  My apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: in Your browser console can you try `jQuery` and `$ == jQuery` and share the results

Comment: I'm assuming `$("div#spinner")` is not a `jQuery` reference, because `jQuery` objects does not have the property `innerHTML`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: 
jQuery
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
$ == jQuery
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: It means your project does not have jQuery in your page, the `$` is coming from some other library. I don't know about `Visual Web Developer 2010`, so you may have to search for how to include `jQuery` in `Visual Web Developer 2010`

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing...you were correct, I was not including the jQuery library.  Although it comes packaged with Visual Web Developer 2010, I still need to add a reference to it.

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer, so that you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the debugging procedures, it looks like your project has not included jQuery library.

Please enable jQuery in your project to make use of jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you should define spinner correctly(i.e. in global)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spinner;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        spinner = $("div#spinner");
    });
    var spinnerVisible = false;
    function showProgress() {
        if (!spinnerVisible) {
            alert(spinner.innerHTML);
            spinner.show();
            spinnerVisible = true;
        }
    };
    function hideProgress() {
        if (spinnerVisible) {
            spinner.hide();
            spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem.  I'm still able to get spinner.innerHTML contents, so I'm fairly confident that jQuery is being able to locate the element, it just is failing on show()/hide() for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the spinner variable without having scope to it in the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var spinner = $("div#spinner");
        });
        var spinnerVisible = false;
        function showProgress() {
            var spinner = $("div#spinner");
            if (!spinnerVisible) {
                alert(spinner.innerHTML);
                spinner.show();
                spinnerVisible = true;
            }
        };
        function hideProgress() {
            var spinner = $("div#spinner");
            if (spinnerVisible) {
                spinner.hide();
                spinnerVisible = false;
            }
        };
    </script>
```