# How to display loading spinner during image load with Url.Action Method in Razor/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, razor, image-manipulation

I'm currently loading an image through an API call in my `Index.cshtml` with this code:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromAPI")" width="500px" />
```

This calls my `HomeController.cs`:

```
public ActionResult ImageFromAPI()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://IP-ADDRESS/snapshot.cgi?channel=0");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic Xwjk15j5oi1gsdg");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response == null)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("~/img/404.jpg"))
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        return File(ms, "image/jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        return File(response.RawBytes, "image/png");
    }
}
```

To explain what's going on - I'm calling my API through the `RestClient` and seeing if it returns something. If so, I output the image to the page, if not, I output the `404` jpg to the page.

The problem is, during the `Url.Action` call (sometimes it takes more than just a second or two), there's no "Image is loading.." substitute.

Is there a proper way to do this? Any/or is there a better way?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/807408/1489570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not load the image directly from a call to the server side.  I would set all images being loaded to some "loading" image on page load and create some functionality with your client side framework to make a call to this action on your server side and replace the loading image with the fully loaded image once it has been received by the client side.